# paper-ripple- fill sibling element in paper-toolbar

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I would like the `paper-ripple` effect to fill`<div class='title bottom'>` also. Any ideas on how to make it do that?

```
  <body unresolved>
      <paper-header-panel shadow="true" 
        mode="waterfall-tall"
        class="fit">
        <paper-toolbar>
          <paper-ripple fit></paper-ripple>
          <div class='title'></div>
          <paper-tabs noink="true" selected="0">
          <!-- only HOME gets route. Others will but down below -->
            <paper-tab class="route" onclick="page('/')">
              HOME
            </paper-tab>
            <paper-tab onclick="page('/resume')">
              RESUME
            </paper-tab>
            <paper-tab>
              CONTACT
            </paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
          <div class='title bottom'>
            <h1 id="name-title">Foo<p> bar<p></h1>
          </div>
        </paper-toolbar>
```

UPDATE...plunker example condenses `paper-header-panel` in non waterfall mode:

```
   <paper-header-panel  
        mode="waterfall-tall"
        class="fit">
        <div>
        <paper-toolbar>
          <paper-tabs>
          <!-- only HOME gets route. Others will but down below -->
            <paper-tab class="route" onclick="page('/')">
              HOME
            </paper-tab>
          </paper-tabs>
        </paper-toolbar>
          <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        </div>

        </paper-header-panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

`paper-toolbar` has three vertically stacked `div`s. So having a `paper-ripple` that takes the whole space is not an option here. What you can do is to wrap the `paper-toolbar` with a *parent* `div` and have the `paper-ripple` sit at the same level as the `paper-toolbar`.

Note that this *parent* `div` needs to have a `paper-header` class so that the `paper-header-panel` knows it's the header and will assign proper styling to it. Also, to constraint the `paper-ripple`, this *parent* `div` needs to be `relative` position.

The last change you need to make is to manually give the `paper-toolbar` a `tall` class since it's no longer the `paper-header-panel`'s direct children.

```
<paper-header-panel mode="waterfall-tall" class="fit">
    <div class="paper-header relative">
        <paper-toolbar class="tall">
            <div class="title"></div>
            <paper-tabs noink selected="0">
                <paper-tab class="route" onclick="page('/')">HOME</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab onclick="page('/resume')">RESUME</paper-tab>
                <paper-tab>CONTACT</paper-tab>
            </paper-tabs>
            <div class="title bottom">
                <h1 id="name-title">Foo<p> bar<p></h1>
            </div>
        </paper-toolbar>

        <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
    </div>
</paper-header-panel>
```

Check out this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zuTi4QjsnSVio7HDfWxh?p=preview).

Comment: I don't know why but the `<div class="paper-header relative"></div>` is forcing the `paper-header-panel` to be condensed in non waterfall mode. *updated original post

Comment: Don't put code in a comment like this, put it in a plunker.